# "Invalid choice" error while using argparse

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script which takes in arguments from command line in the following format:

`./myfile subcommand --change --host=myhost --user=whatever`

`--change` is in a way required, meaning that for now this is only option available, but later I will add other options, but eventually user needs to choose between those options.

`--host` is required. It's not a positional argument.

`--user` is not required, and there is a default value for it. It's not a positional argument.

I'm using the following code to create this command, but 
    #!/usr/bin/env python

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My example explanation')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
subparsers.required = True

subcommand_parser = subparsers.add_parser('subcommand')
subcommand_parser_subparser = subcommand_parser.add_subparsers()
change_subcommand_parser = subcommand_parser_subparser.add_parser('--change')
change_subcommand_parser.add_argument('--host', required=True)
change_subcommand_parser.add_argument('--user', required=False, default='Salam')

print(parser.parse_args())
```

When I try this code with the following command in CLI: 
`./myscript something --change --host hello --user arian`

I get the following error:

`usage: myscript subcommand [-h] {--change} ...
myscript subcommand: error: invalid choice: 'hello' (choose from '--change')`

My questions are:

1. What's wrong with this code?
2. How can I make users type `--user` & `--host`, and not use them as positional arguments?

Comment: Subcommand names cannot be options; use `change`, not `--change`.

Comment: There's probably a bug in `argparse`, but I'm not sure if the bug is allowing you to specify `--change` as a subcommand name, or ignoring options when searching for the subcommand name on the command line.

Comment: apparently removing using `change` instead of `--change` works fine.

Comment: one more question: I have one required argument here: `host`. Is it possible to make it somehow that when users do not provide argument name (--host, --user) it takes the first argument as the host? (make positional unpositional)

Comment: If `host` is required, I would just make it a positional argument to begin with. `required=True` on options is a bit of an antipattern. From the documentation: "Note Required options are generally considered bad form because users expect options to be optional, and thus they should be avoided when possible."

Comment: How positional arguments vs. options are distinguished? only based on how we name them (having `--` in front of them)?

Comment: Yes (although `-` is just the default choice for the prefix characters).